# Boot Windows 7 from separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop for a year now. Today, I got Windows 7 and installed it on a separate drive with the Ubuntu drive removed. Now I can boot each OS by interrupting the BIOS and changing the boot order, so I know both bootloaders work, but when I ran `sudo update-grub` and `sudo udpate-grub2`, Windows was not listed. What can I do to add Windows to grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to locate and mount the Windows partition first, then run `sudo update-grub`.

For example,

`sudo fdisk -l`

results

```
/dev/sda1            2048  53035007 53032960 25.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        53035008  99139583 46104576   22G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        99139584 141266943 42127360 20.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4  *    141266944 215681023 74414080 35.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

in this case the Windows partition is /dev/sda4 (because of NTFS Type and because I know it). Then,

`sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt`

and then

`sudo update-grub`

Windows entry in grub.cfg is nothing special. It is just a chainloader entry. If above method fails to identify Windows properly, then you can manually add the entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file.

Example of Windows `40_custom` entry for MBR (not GPT)

```
menuentry "Windows 7 64bit" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        chainloader +1
}
```

What matters here is the `set root` parameter. hd0,msdos4 = /dev/sda4. If you have more than one HDDs then it might be hd1,msdos4 = /dev/sdb4.

If you follow the manual method, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after editing the `40_custom` file.

Comment: Does that code go in grub.cfg, or 40_custom?

Comment: The code goes to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` , then `sudo update-grub`, but first try the automatic discover by mounting the Windows partition and running `sudo update-grub`. In any case, do not copy-paste the code from here, this is just an example (of my system). You should change the /dev/sda4 partition with yours.

Comment: `fdisk` won't show the windows partition because the disk is formatted with GPT, so I used `parted`. Is the correct partition the one with the `boot` flag, the `msftres` flag, or the `ntfs` partition type? Thanks for your patience, by the way.

EDIT: I'm sure the `boot` flagged partition isn't used by Ubuntu, because this disk was blank when I installed windows, if that matters.

Comment: If you have GPT, you can use `gdisk` instead. Also you must change other entries as well, `insmod part_msdos` to `insmod part_gpt` . Above example code is for MBR, not GPT. You can edit your question and add the results of `parted` command and also you can try both NTFS and msftres types with separate entries in `40_custom` and see what is work.

Comment: Then you cannot boot from grub. You need to totally reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Of if Ubuntu drive is gpt but BIOS boot then convert to UEFI. Grub will only boot systems installed in same boot mode either UEFI or BIOS as Ubuntu install. So all systems should be installed in the same boot mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Tried 3 times to back up my home folder before formatting my drive, with 3 different errors. I'll just stick to switching through the BIOS until I have more patience. Thanks for the help, though, I'll comment here if I get it to work.

Comment: I've reinstalled Ubuntu on the drive where I installed Windows. Now Windows shows up in the grub menu, but my computer doesn't boot grub by default, it boots Windows.

Comment: And how you managed to show grub in first place ? Maybe you need to change the boot order in BIOS/UEFI ?

Comment: For some reason, booting Ubuntu is only an option from the boot menu and not the BIOS setup. I can only select the drive from the BIOS, and there the drive is labelled "UEFI Hard Drive: Windows Boot Manager."

Comment: Probably this is because the UEFI implementation as @oldfred said above. Maybe you can't boot from the other HDD because of "Secure Boot" ? that's my guess.

Comment: When I re-installed Ubuntu, I selected the unformatted portion of my SSD to mount at "/" and created a swap partition, and left everything else as default. This is the only thing I can think of that could have gone wrong; was I supposed to have the Windows boot sector mounted to /boot, or make some other change?